# Can the type of the current class be used as the value of a generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

Can something like this be accomplished using C#?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract IInterface<T> CreateEditor() where T: the_actual_type_of_this_instance;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var instance = new DerivedClass();
var editor = instance.CreateEditor(); // IInterface<DerivedClass>
```

Comment: No. See Eric Lippert's [Curiouser and Curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) for related issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that - partly because it wouldn't make sense at compile time. Consider a *slight* change to your code:

```
BaseClass instance = new DerivedClass();
var editor = instance.CreateEditor();
```

What could the compiler infer the type of `editor` to be? It only knows about `BaseClass`, so it would have to return an `IInterface<BaseClass>`. Depending on whether or not `T` in `IInterface<T>` is covariant, that could be valid for something which *actually* implemented `IInterface<DerivedClass>` or it might not be.

You might want to make your base class generic instead:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract IInterface<T> CreateEditor();
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
{
    ...
}
```

There are two problems with this:

- It doesn't work when you go more than one level deep; if you need subclasses of `DerivedClass`, you'll have issues
- It doesn't prevent *malicious* abuse of the pattern, e.g. `public class NastyClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>`

... but in many cases it's quite practical.